# how to make the front page of joomla consist of only one article, or one section?

Tags: joomla

Currently, the joomla front page consists of latest news and several articles and list, basiclly i want to change the layout of this to just one specific article.

Changing the home button properties on the menu page doesnt do the trick as thats not the same as the front page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the menu manager and find the default menu item. It is marked with a star.  Edit that item. If it is using a frontpage/featured layout you can tell it exactly how many featured articles do display by changing the parameters. OR you can change the menu item o a single article or a category or whatever you want.